# 'ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found.\r\n' } on VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, importerror

'ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified module could not be found.\r\n'
}
Error 13:41:09: Failed to execute cells in CellExecutionQueue o [Error]: The kernel died. View Jupyter log for further details.

i've made an env and i wanna run the kernel with the env but i got this problem
[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EbvZ.png)

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fztiu.png)

[image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by7hm.png)

Answer (score 1):

The following conclusions can be drawn from the relevant information

```
python has this module built-in, anaconda doesn't
```

The workaround is to place a sqlite3.DLL file named in the DDLs directory:

```
..\Anaconda\DLLs
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when running a Django api from a virtual environment. I just copied the `sqlite3.dll` file from `..\Anaconda3\Library\bin` to `my_virtual_env\Scripts` and it worked just as normally as expected.